# Wrap text around video using bootstrap 4.3.1

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to wrap my head around this, but I just can't seem to make it work.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 order-1 mb-auto mt-auto">
                <article>
                    <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Miért jó a töltőtoll?</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="text-justify">Egy igazán jó töltőtoll akár egész életünkben hű társunk lehet az írás területén. Aki igényes és szeretné, hogy azok az írások, amiket készít nagyon szépek legyenek azoknak érdemes a töltőtollak között szétnézni. A töltőtollal készített írások teljesen máshogy néznek ki mint a golyóstollal készítettek, sokkal szebbek és igényesebbek. Egy töltőtoll sokkal szebben és igényesebben kidolgozott íróeszköz mint az egyszerűbb golyóstollak, arról nem is beszélve, hogy sokkal tartósabbak mint a golyóstollak. Egy jó töltőtollal az írás érzete is sokkal jobb, csak úgy siklik a papíron a tollnak a hegye. A toll tartásának a változtatásával pedig más és más vastagságú írás módot alkalmazhatunk. Ez pedig egy elegáns írásképet ad a töltőtoll tulajdonosának. A töltőtollakhoz, többféle színű tintát kapunk így még színesebbé tehetjük az írást.</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p class= "text-justify hide-on-print">A videóhoz tartozó leírás <a href="leiras.xhtml">elérhető ezen a linken.</a></p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 order-2 hide-on-print">
                <figure>
                    <video class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 mb-auto mt-auto" controls poster="images/poster.png">
                        <source class="embed-responsive-item" src="images/video.mp4">
                        <source class="embed-responsive-item" src="images/video.ogg">
                        Nem támogatja a videó tagot a böngésző.
                    </video>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have this code currently, which makes the text appear in 2 or 1 columns depending on the device, but I want it to wrap around the video like
this:

[image]

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong? I tried adding float right to the figure's div, but it made no impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood You right, text should wrap around video. But if You separate text and video into columns, text can't wrap around video.
To achieve this behavior, video should be in the same container with text:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-auto mt-auto">
      <article>
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Miért jó a töltőtoll?</h1>
        <hr>
        <p class="text-justify">
          <figure class="float-right">
            <video class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" controls poster="images/poster.png">
              <source class="embed-responsive-item" src="images/video.mp4">
              <source class="embed-responsive-item" src="images/video.ogg">
              Nem támogatja a videó tagot a böngésző.
            </video>
          </figure>
          Egy igazán jó töltőtoll akár egész életünkben hű társunk lehet az írás területén. Aki igényes és szeretné, hogy azok az írások, amiket készít nagyon szépek legyenek azoknak érdemes a töltőtollak között szétnézni. A töltőtollal készített írások teljesen máshogy néznek ki mint a golyóstollal készítettek, sokkal szebbek és igényesebbek. Egy töltőtoll sokkal szebben és igényesebben kidolgozott íróeszköz mint az egyszerűbb golyóstollak, arról nem is beszélve, hogy sokkal tartósabbak mint a golyóstollak. Egy jó töltőtollal az írás érzete is sokkal jobb, csak úgy siklik a papíron a tollnak a hegye. A toll tartásának a változtatásával pedig más és más vastagságú írás módot alkalmazhatunk. Ez pedig egy elegáns írásképet ad a töltőtoll tulajdonosának. A töltőtollakhoz, többféle színű tintát kapunk így még színesebbé tehetjük az írást.
        </p>
        <hr>
        <p class="text-justify hide-on-print">A videóhoz tartozó leírás <a href="leiras.xhtml">elérhető ezen a linken.</a></p>

      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/ak9dpfLm/